# In PostgreSQL, efficiently using a table for every row in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I am sorry for the lack of notation in my question but I am not too familiar with SQL. Despite searching the internet for a decent amount of hours, I couldn't find that how to do efficiently what I wanted to do, but that is maybe because I am not familiar with the notation. Here comes the question:

I want to create a table, say Forms, in which each Form row has an ID, some metadata and a pointer(?) to the table of that Form row, lets say Form12 table, which directs me to Form12 table. I need it because every Form has different number, name and type of columns depending on users configuration for a particular Form.

So, I thought I can put the Table ID of Form12 as a column to Form table. But is this approach considered OK, or is there a better way to do it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can use jeson datatype as one of the column i guess that will solve your purpose

Comment: @smn_onrocks i will check that out, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the names of tables in a column is generally not a good solution in a relational database.  In order to use the information, you need to use dynamic SQL.

I would instead ask why you cannot store the information in a single table or well-defined sets of tables.  Postgres has lots of options to help with this:

- `NULL` data values, so columns do not need to be filled in.
- Table inheritance, so tables can share columns.
- JSON columns to support a flexible set of columns.
- Entity-attribute-value (EAV) data models, which allow for lots of flexibility.

Comment: thx for your answer, as i said i am no expert, just took an sql course in college. could i ask, for storing the information in a single table in the case that there might be, in the end (since someone can just add another Form with different variables), exist large amount of columns, which approach would you choose? i am going to research on things you stated, but need some bias :)

Comment: @OzgurBagci . . . You may have a good use-case for table inheritance:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html.